# Solving an equation with large exponents with python

Tags: python, math, scipy, sympy, equation

I am trying to compute the Yield to Maturity of a bond using the following equation, considering the current price, number of periods, coupons and face value are all known.

[image: img]

I have created a SymPy expression using the following code:

```py
expr = coupon/pow((1+ytm), exp)
exp= exp+0.5

for x in range(1, periods):
    expr = expr + coupon/pow((1+ytm), exp)
    exp = exp+0.5

exp = exp-0.5
expr = expr+100/pow((1+ytm), exp)
```

The expression looks like this once computed:

```py
Out[3]: 104.375*(ytm + 1)**(-28.7356164383562) + 4.375*(ytm + 1)**(-28.2356164383562) + ..... + 4.375*(ytm + 1)**(-0.735616438356164) + 4.375*(ytm + 1)**(-0.235616438356164)
```

Tried to solve with the SymPy `solve()` method:

```py
from sympy.solvers import solve
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Any help on how I should approach this problem is appreciated a lot.

Comment: Would scipy [financial functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.financial.html) be useful?

Comment: To me it looks like you are interested in a numerical solution, not a symbolic one. Have a look at `scipy.optimize.newton` for that. Otherwise showing the whole code would help so that others can see how to fix it.

Comment: @ChrisCharley not sure it helps for this, but very useful for other things i will do for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerical solutions can be obtained easily with `nsolve`. Demonstrating with an expression derived from what you gave:

```
>>> print(filldedent(eq))
104.375*(ytm + 1)**(-28.7356164383562) + 4.375*(ytm +
1)**(-28.2356164383562) + 4.375*(ytm + 1)**(-0.735616438356164) +
4.375*(ytm + 1)**(-0.235616438356164)
>>> nsolve(eq-5, 1)
2.49587148297981
```